# Linear Output Regulation Problem and Invariant Modal Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

I'm trying to learn the full information linear output regulation problem from [this set of slides](https://www2.ece.ohio-state.edu/%7Eserrani/research/presentations/NTNU05/lecture1.pdf) (p. 5-15), for which our goal is to steer the following linear system
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= Ax + Bu + Pw \\
\dot{w} &= Sw \\
e &= Cx + Qw
\end{align}
$$
such that the error $e \rightarrow \mathbf{0} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, given **known** matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, P \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}, Q \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times d}$, and $S \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. The system state is $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, control input is $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and the reference/disturbance signal is $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ generated by the *exo-system* $\dot{w} = Sw$, and all eigenvalues of $S$ have nonnegative real part.

If we define $\xi = (x, w)$ and design a controller $u = Kx$ for some matrix $K$ such that $A+BK$ is stable (i.e., all eigenvalues have negative real part, and the problem assumes that this is possible to do), then from the equations above we can write
$$
\dot{\xi} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
A+BK & P \\
\mathbf{0} & S
\end{bmatrix}}_{A_{cl}}
\xi
$$
Due to the assumption that the eigenvalues of $A+BK$ and $S$ are disjoint, the author claims that this matrix induces two indepedent modal subspaces spanned by
$$
\mathcal{V}^+ = \mathrm{col} \begin{bmatrix}
I_n \\ \mathbf{0}
\end{bmatrix}, 
\qquad
\mathcal{V}^- = \mathrm{col} \begin{bmatrix}
\Pi \\ I_d
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
where $\mathrm{col}$ represents the column space of a matrix.

**Here's what I don't really understand:**

- For the proposed $\mathcal{V}^+, \mathcal{V}^-$ modal subspaces to have that form (which seems to imply that $\mathcal{V}^+ \oplus \mathcal{V}^- = \mathbb{R}^{n+d}$), don't we need distinCt eigenvalues for $A+BK$ and $S$? Alternatively, each repeated eigenvalue has algebraic multiplicity = geometric multiplicity. There seems to be no indication why this would always be the case.
- More importantly, on p. 12 the author claims that $\mathcal{V}^+$ is $A_{cl}$-invariant. Is this because eigenspaces are invariant under the linear operator?

I'd appreciate any clarifications on this.

Comment: No, what is needed here is that the eigenvalues of $A+BK$ and $S$ be disjoint. I guess you are confusing here eigenspaces and invariant subspaces. An invariant subspace $\mathcal{V}$ of a linear operator $A$ verifies $A\mathcal{V}\subseteq \mathcal{V}$. Of cours an eigenspace is an invariant subspace but the latter concept is more general (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace) On page 12, it is not claimed that $\mathcal{V}^+$ is $A_{cl}$ inavriant, it is an observation of page 11, just do the calculations to convince yourself.